# Strange behavior na_values parameter in read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a csv file that contains in some columns the string 'na' which I want to be read as 'NaN'. For that reason I use the parameter na_values:

```py
data=pd.read_csv('myFile.csv', header=1, skipfooter=1, na_values=['na'])
```

But in the dataframe the 'na' strings remains in my columns

Pandas version 0.23.4

Some sample data

```
field   year    value_n
A   2001    58.665047
T   2002    57.199509
E   2018    64.186355
B   2002     na
C   2016    29.563211
A   2017    29.244814
T   2018    29.757972
E   2002     na
B   2014    40.099364
C   2015    38.79734
A   2016    37.516027
T   2017    36.483568
E   2018    37.11407
B   2002     na
```

Comment: Could you please share a data sample?

Comment: Is there any extra space before and or after the na sentinel?

Comment: Your strings are not `'na'` but `' na'` (note space). Also `read_csv`s default separator is `,`. So you also want to set the correct `sep` parameter.

Comment: That was the problem!! there are some 'na' and some ' na' with na_values=['na', ' na'] it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the keep_default_na parameter for proper parsing of NaN values.

Comment: According to the documentation is True by default: 'keep_default_na : bool, default True' I have added it to my code to give it a try and the result is the same